# Proof verification: Equivalent definitions of weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, weak-convergence

I am trying to write the proof for two equivalent approaches of defining weak convergence of probability measures, as presented in Billingsley (1999) "Convergence of probability measures". I would appreciate any comments on this.

**Theorem (Equivalent definitions of weak convergence)**

Let $(S,\rho)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{S}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $(P_n)$ and $P$ be probability measures on $\mathcal{S}$. The following are equivalent:

1. $P_n(A) \rightarrow P(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $P(\partial A)=0$
2. $\int_SfdP_n \rightarrow \int_SfdP$ for each bounded, continuous real function $f$ on $S$

**Proof**

($2 \implies 1$)
Theorem 1.1 (Billingsley, 1999) implies that $P$ is regular, and so $P_n$ and $P$ are completely determined by the values of $(P_n)(F)$ and $P(F)$ for the closed sets $F$. Our goal is to approximate the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{F}$ by some bounded, continuous real function $f$ on $S$. Let

$
f :=
\begin{cases}
(1-\rho(x,F)/\epsilon) \quad \text{if} \quad (1-\rho(x,F)/\epsilon)>0\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$

where $\rho(x,F) := \inf \left\{\rho(x,y):y \in F\right\}$.
The function $f$ is bounded and it is continuous because $  |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \rho(x,y)/\epsilon$.
Let $F^\epsilon:=\{x:\rho(x,F)<\epsilon\}$. If $x \in F$, then $f(x)=1$. On the other hand, if $x \notin F^\epsilon$, then $f(x)=0$, so
$
\mathbf{1}_{F}(x) \leq f(x) \leq \mathbf{1}_{F^\epsilon}(x).
$
Then
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P_n(F)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_S\mathbf{1}_{F}dP_n\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_SfdP_n=\int_SfdP \leq  P(F^\epsilon).$

Since $F$ is a closed set,
$\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}F^\epsilon=\overline{F}=F$,
so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(F)\leq P(F)$. By symmetry, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(F)= P(F)$.

($1 \implies 2$)  Since $f$ is bounded and continuous, it is measurable. Since $S$ has finite measure, it follows that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and so
\begin{equation*}
     \int_SfdP_n=\sup\left \{\int_S\phi dP_n: \phi \text{ is simple} \right\}. 
\end{equation*}
By definition,  each $\phi$ can be written as a linear combination of finitely many indicator functions of disjoint measurable sets, i.e.,
$f=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i}$, so $\int_S\phi dP_n=\sum_{i=1}^ka_iP_n(A_i)$.

*But now I am missing on the condition $P(\partial A)=0$ and not sure how to include it.*

Comment: Isn't this fully covered in the proof to Theorem 2.1 of the book you referenced?

Comment: @Zhanxiong it is, I realised it later. It's just the way that particular section is written feels like this statement should follow immediately from the two theorems in Section 1. Thanks for commenting!